# CUDA: Strategies for concurrently running kernels with varying resource requirements

Tags: cuda

What's a good way to concurrently schedule multiple kernels with varying resource requirements, so that resource usage is balanced across the set?

For example, I have kernel `K_Compute`, which is compute-bound (resulting in math-pipe stalls), and kernel `K_Memory` which is memory-bandwidth-bound.
Ideally, they'd be scheduled to run concurrently on the same SM, so that the overall resource usage is balanced.

I'm aware that having multiple streams allows the scheduler to add concurrency, but I don't know how the scheduler works (is this documented?) or whether it's already doing something clever.

If it's not being clever and is just assigning the next available kernel to the next available SM, I'd like to know things like:

1. How does it define the next available kernel? I'm currently assuming something like one FIFO queue per stream with breadth-first (circular) scheduling.
2. How does it define the next available SM? Does it try to spread work evenly across the SMs, or does it try to pack as much work as possible onto SM `i` before moving onto SM `i+1`?

Comment: You should not only consider SMs, but  (the 4) SM partitions, as far as compute stalls go. There are different (cache) levels of memory boundness. You probably mean global memory? Then the memory bound kernel can run anywhere on the GPU (you will fill memory bandwidth even from a few blocks). You can influence the distribution of the kernels by reserving the right amount of shared memory by both kernels. Or by starting both as the same kernel and doing the respective function depending on where the specific block is running.

Comment: Mixing the blocks with the last method or just by scheduling this way could lead to overfilling the instruction cache easier. There is a not so important size per partition and a more important limit per SM. E.g. on Turing it is about 6000 continuously executed SASS instructions, when instruction fetch stalls occur more often.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! 1) Yes I was talking about global memory bandwidth. I'm surprised it doesn't matter which SMs do the loading - I guess they don't have private memory buses, only a shared bus? 2) Interesting idea about shared memory reservations. 3) I've tried creating a "meta-kernel" which then calls the actual kernels, like you suggested, but not via CUDA Dynamic Parallelism (just regular function calls). It's worth a shot.

Comment: 1) L2 is nearly fast enough for the SMs (good bandwidth, mediocre latency), but global memory can be a real bottleneck. The global memory bandwidth is shared between all SMs. 2) You can also play around with the number of registers. Normally the warps of a block are distributed within a SM to fill one of the 4 Partitions after the other and only then start with the first Partition again. 3) I meant just function calls within kernels. However, Dynamic Parallelism got upgraded with device side task graphs, which improve performance, but it has no advantage for your use case compared to functions

Comment: 2) I've tried to reduce register usage without much luck. I've seen some papers where they store register spills in shared memory, and I think that approach would work, but it's not something I'm willing to do manually at the moment. 3) My kernels have different optimal occupancy, so I think I'd need something like Dynamic Parallelism to change the number of threads (I haven't really looked into it, though).

Comment: For 2) I did not intend to suggest actually changing the algorithm with shared memory or register use. Rather just the values to be reserved for the kernels. If your SM has 64 KB of shared memory, you can demand 17 KB with the first kernel, making sure that only up to 3 blocks are started per SM. Even if your kernel needs no or less shared memory.

Comment: The same goes for registers. In this way, you can control how many resources (except shared memory) stay free on the SM for the second kernel. The numbers were just examples. You should know the max. threads (=> max warps) per SM, max blocks per SM, max. registers per SM ... and decide on how many warps of each kernel you want to start per SM. You could also combine more than one of your blocks into one block without changing the code (except to account for threadIdx and blockIdx). E.g. put 7 blocks in 1. This fixes a multiple of 7 like 7 or 14 original blocks per SM, but not 6, 8, 13 or 15.

Comment: 3) Even with different max. occupancy per kernel, you can finetune: E.g. You want to start 7 warps per SM of kernel 1 and 17 warps per SM of kernel 2. Those are 24 warps per SM altogether. Warp 0, 4, 8, 12, 16 and 20 goes into Partition 1; 1, 5, 9, ..., 21 into Partition 2; and so on. You want to distribute your kernels regularly on the 4 Partitions. So each Partition should get 1 or 2 warps of kernel 1. Start the combined kernel with dim3(32, 24) for blockdim. Check for threadIdx.y < 7 run kernel 1, else run kernel 2. Now the occupancy of your kernels has the ratio 7/17.

Comment: Putting several blocks of one kernel or two kernels into one combined thread block has few side effects. a) Of course it is larger, so you have to carefully check, how the occupancy is on the target hardware. Lots of the mentioned methods can be applied at runtime to dynamically account for the hardware. b) If you need to use syncthreads() for block-level synchronization and do not want to have unrelated blocking, there is the customized variant of 16 barriers, where you can choose which warps participate and which of those wait=block and which just have to arrive for the others to continue.

Comment: And which warps do not care at all for the barrier (and are not cared for by the other warps). c) Your kernels would start at the same time. Some warps ending prematurly is no problem. If you plan to run kernels at the same time at all, starting them absolutely at the same time should be okay, too. Except you want to use the results of one kernel for the other. This can probably be also handled, but would also be nontrivial for starting the two kernels concurrently on two streams.